# Ruby synchronized ouput from $stdout and $stderr

Tags: ruby, stdout, stderr

I am writing a program that is made up of various subprograms, each of which log their own errors. At the end of execution I would like to dump all errors that where encountered to the screen labelled by the program that logged them.

Ideally I would have something like this:

```
Encountered 4 errors during compilation (STDOUT)
   Tokenizer Errors: (STDOUT)
      Line 4: Invalid symbol found '@' (STDERR)

   Parser Errors: (STDOUT)
      Line 7: expected 'end' but saw 'while' (STDERR)   
      Line 7: expected ';' but saw 'while'   (STDERR)
      Line 12 expected '.' but saw 'end'  (STDERR)
```

But when I run my program the $stdout lines and the $stderr lines are getting mixed up. I know that $stdout buffers and $stderr doesn't, so I added this line to the method that prints the output:

```
$stdout.sync = $stderr.sync = true
```

which I have been told should sync the two output streams. But unfortunately I still receive jumbled output. I also tried adding `$stdout.flush` after every line I wanted sent to $stdout, but that also seems to have no effect.

Here is the code I am using:

```
  def self.dump()
     $stdout.sync = $stderr.sync = true # attempted sync
     if not @@lexer_error_log.empty? or not @@parser_error_log.empty?
        puts "Encountered #{@@err_cnt} errors during compilation\n" 
        $stdout.flush #flush
     end

     if not @@lexer_error_log.empty?
       puts "\nTokenizer Errors:"
       $stdout.flush # flush
       @@lexer_error_log.each {|e| $stderr.puts "\t#{e}\n" }
     end 

     if not @@parser_error_log.empty?
       puts "Parser Errors:"
       $stdout.flush # flush
       @@parser_error_log.each {|e| $stderr.puts "\t#{e}\n" }
     end 
   end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach: collect the error output into a `String` with something like this:

```
require 'stringio'

so = $stderr
$stderr = StringIO.new('', 'w')

# run your program
```

And then either restore `$stderr` or just print the string to `$stdout`...

```
puts $stderr.string
```

Comment: Since the `\n` that `puts` adds is done as a separate write, you probably want to output a `\n` to the `StringIO` and use `print` rather than `puts`.